# Coherence between Hamiltonian and Lagrangian in form of an inequality (Evans PDE)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, sobolev-spaces, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I need some help with 2 things in Evan's Partial Differential Equations. Both being part of chapter 3.3.3, proof of Lemma 4.
Our prerequisite is that H is uniformly convex, i.e.:
$$\sum_{i.j=1}^{n} H_{p_ip_j}(p)\xi_i \xi_j \geq \theta |\xi|^2 \;\;\forall p,\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n. \;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
Now Evans claims that this implies (with Taylor's formula)
$$H\left(\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{2}H(p_1)+\frac{1}{2}H(p_2)-\frac{\theta}{8}|p_1-p_2|^2. \;\;\;\;\;(2)$$
But I don't know how to prove it.
Here's what I have:
$$
H(x + \xi) \overset{Taylor}{=} H(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} H_{p_i} (x) \xi_i + 2 \sum_{|\alpha|=2} \int_{0}^{1} (1-t) \frac{D^\alpha H(x+t\xi)}{\alpha!} \xi^\alpha dt
$$
$$
= H(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} H_{p_i} (x) \xi_i + \int_{0}^{1} (1-t) \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} H_{p_i p_j} (x+t\xi) \xi_i \xi_j dt
$$
$$
\overset{(1)}{\geq} H(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} H_{p_i} (x) \xi_i + \frac{\theta}{2}|\xi|^2.
$$
So now we choose $\xi = \frac{p_1-p_2}{2}$, $x = \frac{p_1+p_2}{2}$:
$$
\Rightarrow H(p_1) \geq H\left(\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}\right) + \nabla H\left(\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2}\left(p_1-p_2\right) + \frac{\theta}{8}\left| p_1-p_2 \right|^2.
$$
My problem is how to eliminate the gradient term in the middle. I thought about using the mean value theorem but $\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}$ doesn't have to be the right value for it.

After that Evans goes on and claims that $(2)$ implies
$$
\frac{1}{2}L(q_1)+\frac{1}{2}L(q_2) \leq L\left(\frac{q_1+q_2}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{8\theta}|q_1-q_2|^2. \;\;\;\;\;(3)
$$
The only idea I have is that the direct coherence between $H$ and $L$ can be expressed as
$$
\forall q_1, q_2 \text{ there exist }p_1, p_2\text{ such that }H(p_i) + L(q_i) = p_i \cdot q_i.
$$
I really hope you can help me proving formula $(2)$ and $(3)$.
Thanks in advance,
Zhorrid.

Comment: You only obtained an estimate on $H(p_1)$, but you can get an estimate on $H(p_2)$ by choosing the same $x$ and the opposite $\xi$. Adding these two should get you (2).

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you so much!  
About formula (3): My professor told me the fact that $D^2 H = (D^2 L)^{-1}$ could help solving the problem. But I have no idea how to use that in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is nearly 4 years too late, but I thought that I would share it, just encase anybody else has trouble with this.

$H$ is $C^2$ and so $\forall p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have by Taylor's Theorem (with Lagrange remainder) that $\exists t \in (0,1)$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
H(p_1) = & H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} + \frac{p_1 - p_2}{2} \right ) \\
= & H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) + DH \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) \cdot \left (\frac{p_1 - p_2}{2} \right ) \\
& + \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{p_1 - p_2}{2} \right )^TD^2H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} + t\frac{p_1 - p_2}{2} \right ) \left (\frac{p_1 - p_2}{2} \right ) \\
\geq & H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) + DH \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) \cdot \left (\frac{p_1 - p_2}{2} \right ) +  \frac{\theta}{8}|p_1 - p_2|^2.
\end{align*}
Where the last line follows from the fact that $H$ is uniformly convex. Similarly we get
$$ H(p_2) \geq H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) + DH \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) \cdot \left (\frac{p_2 - p_1}{2} \right ) +  \frac{\theta}{8}|p_1 - p_2|^2. $$
Adding these two inequalities and dividing by 2, we get
$$
\frac{1}{2} H(p_1) + \frac{1}{2} H(p_2) \geq H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) +  \frac{\theta}{8}|p_1 - p_2|^2.
$$
Thus by taking away $\frac{\theta}{8}|p_1 - p_2|^2$ from both sides, we get the desired inequality. For the next part, we use the fact that $L = H^*$ and that the supremum is attained because of the conditions on $H$ ($H$ is continuous and $\lim_{|p| \to \infty} \frac{H(p)}{|p|} = \infty$), that is
$$
L(v) = \max_{p \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left \{v \cdot p - H(p) \right \}.
$$
We also use Young's inequality to get that $\forall p_1,p_2,v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have
\begin{align*}
\left( \frac{p_1 - p_2}{2} \right ) \cdot \left( \frac{v_1 - v_2}{2} \right ) &= \left( \sqrt{\theta} \frac{p_1 - p_2}{2} \right ) \cdot \left( \frac{v_1 - v_2}{2\sqrt{\theta}} \right )\\  &\leq \frac{\theta}{8} |p_1 - p_2|^2 + \frac{1}{8\theta} |v_1 - v_2|^2.
\end{align*}
So for each $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n, \exists p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t.
$$
L(v_i) = v_i \cdot p_i - H(p_i)
$$
for $i = 1,2$. Now
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} L(v_1) + \frac{1}{2} L(v_2) = & \frac{1}{2} v_1 \cdot p_1 + \frac{1}{2} v_2 \cdot p_2 - \frac{1}{2}H(p_1) - \frac{1}{2}H(p_2) \\
\leq & \frac{1}{2} v_1 \cdot p_1 + \frac{1}{2} v_2 \cdot p_2 - H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) -  \frac{\theta}{8}|p_1 - p_2|^2.
\end{align*}
Where we have applied the first inequality for $H$. Next
\begin{align*}
&= \frac{1}{2} v_1 \cdot p_1 + \frac{1}{2} v_2 \cdot p_2 - H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) + \frac{1}{8\theta} |v_1 - v_2|^2 -  \left ( \frac{\theta}{8}|p_1 - p_2|^2 + \frac{1}{8\theta} |v_1 - v_2|^2 \right ) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2} v_1 \cdot p_1 + \frac{1}{2} v_2 \cdot p_2 - H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) + \frac{1}{8\theta} |v_1 - v_2|^2 - \left( \frac{p_1 - p_2}{2} \right ) \cdot \left( \frac{v_1 - v_2}{2} \right )
\end{align*}
Where we have applied Young's inequality, next we multiply out the brackets to get
\begin{align*}
& = \left( \frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) \cdot \left( \frac{v_1 + v_2}{2} \right ) - H \left (\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} \right ) + \frac{1}{8\theta} |v_1 - v_2|^2 \\
& \leq L\left( \frac{v_1 + v_2}{2} \right ) + \frac{1}{8\theta} |v_1 - v_2|^2.
\end{align*}
Where the last line follows from the fact that $L = H^*$. So we are done.